# Is attaching a database on the same server under a different database name possible?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recovery

I recently offered to help a friend with some development. She isn't a technical person and it turned out what she needed was more a DBA/SQL developer. She gave me the IP and password to this server.

There is no development server. Only production. So I have to be extra careful with everything I do.

I accidentally altered a stored procedure and now I'm trying to get it back. I had the old employees send me the lastest files. They were in rar format and after I unzipped the DB folder, there was only a file inside(no extension). Looking at the contents led me to believe it is a SQL Server .mdf file. This leads me to my question.

Can I attach this mdf file to a new database I just created? Without it trying to take down the other instance? It seems like I could but since this is production, I have to be EXTRA careful.

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2, with SQL Server Management Studio 2012 installed.

Comment: You have already learned the lesson, but make sure you script your db objects to avoid a situation like this in the future.

Comment: @jj you are correct

Answer (score 3):

You can first check to make sure it actually is a valid MDF file [using DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3342/how-to-use-dbcc-checkprimaryfile-to-attach-several-sql-server-databases-in-seconds/). It is an undocumented command but can be useful at times.

If that turns up nothing or shows that it is not a mdf file you can use the RESTORE HEADERONLY to see if it might be a backup file.

To your specific question, yes you can attach this as a different database name as long as the physical file is not in the same directory on the server as the original. So in your case I would just create a sub-directory in your data folder for this file and the future LDF file that would be created.

Comment: Shawn, turns out I had saved the stored procedure and didn't have to use the mdf they provided me. I followed your link to DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE, and read up anyways. Thanks. I do have another question though... SSMS is unable to create a database diagram for the main database. My question is, "Can I create a new database with that mdf?". I created a mock database, to see if the issue of not being able to create a diagram was only for the main database. Sure enough, you can create diagrams for new databases. SO how could I copy the current db to a new one, so I can extract the diagram?

Comment: I would take the error or information you are getting when trying to create diagrams and post as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes ONLY if the files are not in use.

USE [master] 
GO
CREATE DATABASE [YourDataBase] ON 
( FILENAME = N'Path....\FileName1_Data.MDF' ),-- Data files (mdf/ndf)
( FILENAME = N'Path....\FileName2_log.ldf' ) -- log files (ldf)
 FOR ATTACH
GO

Comment: If you read OP question he asked `Can I attach this mdf file to a new database I just created?`  the answer should be no you cannot and in fact you should not. You must attach it as different database whose name is not same as prod

Comment: As Shanky mentioned, you can't attach to an existing database, but you can create a new one and use the mdf/ldf as the source files like @itzik Paz described. If you only have the mdf, you'll need to use CREATE DATABASE [NewDBName] ... FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG. Also, go grab the trial, you can use it for 180 days free or get a dev copy for your own use. It should only cost $60 or you can build a new VM every 6 months... or at least get sql express which will work with DBs up to 10 GB.